# Как получить результат числового математического выражения, переданного в textview

Tags: android

Возможно, есть какой-то короткий путь решения проблемы, которая состоит в следующем:

Есть поле textview, которое содержит числовое выражение (т.е. только цифры), к примеру, 1+1.

Есть переменная result, которая должна вычислять ответ этого выражения, т.е. result=1+1.

Я сейчас представляю себе только "длинный" путь решения проблемы, в котором есть 3 (а не одно) textview, содержащие части выражения, и из textview   можно извлечь данные типа String и преобразовать их в данные типа int и т.п.

Но, возможно, эту задачу можно решить как-то проще, прошу поделиться мыслями на этот счет.

Comment: В Java нет классов, способных выполнить эту работу. Вам нужно либо поискать готовую библиотеку, возможно кто то уже решал аналогичную задачу по вычислению выражения представленного строкой, либо писать собственный парсер.

Comment: У вас не только цифры в textview, result = 2 вы хотели написать?
Не такой уж длинный путь в вашем случае, а вот если там будут длинные вычисления, тогда сложность резко возрастет. Можеет воспользоваться обычной открытой lib с калькулятором. 
Всё что вам необходимо будет достать String, split его на массив чисел и спец символов и использовать калькулятор. Результат выводим в result. ПО мне самый оптимальный вариант.

Comment: да, спасибо за совет, Ваша идея помогла мне упростить код, можно было написать ее в ответ)

Comment: Есть очень простой алгоритм, который способен решать выражения и со скобками, и с унарными минусами, плюсами и т.д. Он очень простой в понимании, в написании. А так же в него очень удобно заносить новые операции по типу `^` возведение в степень и т.д. Этот алгоритм называет RPN, вот ссылка на википедию где можно почитать о нем: [ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Answer (score 1):

Вот минимальный калькулятор (без всяких проверок на корректность строки и т.п.), умеющий делить-умножать-складывать вычитать без скобок и прочих более сложных вычислений.

```
    public static float splitAndCalculate(String str) {
    List<String> digits = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*\\*|/|\\+|-\\s*")));
    List<String> signs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\s*")));
    for (int i = digits.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (signs.get(i).equals("*") || signs.get(i).equals("/")) {
            if (signs.get(i).equals("*")) {
                digits.set(i - 1, String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(digits.get(i - 1)) * Float.parseFloat(digits.get(i))));
            } else {
                digits.set(i - 1, String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(digits.get(i - 1)) / Float.parseFloat(digits.get(i))));
            }
            digits.remove(i);
            signs.remove(i);
        }
    }
    for (int i = digits.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (signs.get(i).equals("+") || signs.get(i).equals("-")) {
            if (signs.get(i).equals("+")) {
                digits.set(i - 1, String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(digits.get(i - 1)) + Float.parseFloat(digits.get(i))));
            } else {
                digits.set(i - 1, String.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(digits.get(i - 1)) - Float.parseFloat(digits.get(i))));
            }
            digits.remove(i);
            signs.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return Float.parseFloat(digits.get(0));
}
```

Если запустить

```
String str = "3 * 2 / 6.7 + 4 - 1 / 5";
System.out.println(str + " = " + splitAndCalculate(str));
```

То в консоль выведет `3 * 2 / 6.7 + 4 - 1 / 5 = 4.6955223`

Answer (score 0):

Сначала порекомендую все таки использовать готовые библиотеки, а не придумывать велосипед. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form) приведено много вариантов, как в `Java` можно решить математические выражения. (даже есть решение через использование механизма `JavaScript` и вызов функции `eval`. В `js` именно так и решают примеры)

Но, а если в учебных целях, то по моему мнению самый простой и понятный алгоритм решения простых математических выражений это **RPN**, или "Обратная польская нотация". Подробней можете почитать на [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C).

Далее я приведу код с комментариями. За основу взял код со статьи на [Habr](https://habr.com/ru/articles/596925/). Но добавил например возможность использовать числа с плавающей запятой.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    // Парсинг числа в expr начиная с позици pos
    public static String GetStringNumber(String expr, int pos) {
        String strNumber = "";
        // Была ли добавлена точка
        boolean hasDot = false;
        for (; pos < expr.length(); pos++) {
            char num = expr.charAt(pos);
            if (num == '.') {
                // Если точка уже была добавлена и мы нашли еще одну
                // просто заканчиваем парсинг
                if (hasDot) break;
                hasDot = true;
            }
            else if (!Character.isDigit(num))
                break;
            strNumber += num;
        }
        return strNumber;
    }
    
    // Ключ - оператор, значение - приоритет
    public static Map<Character, Integer> operationPriority = Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry('(', 0),
        Map.entry('+', 1),
        Map.entry('-', 1),
        Map.entry('*', 2),
        Map.entry('/', 2),
        Map.entry('~', 4)
    );
    
    // Функция, которая возвращает результат операции op 
    // над двумя числами first и second
    private static double ExecuteOperator(char op, double first, double second) {
        switch(op) {
            case ('+'): return first + second;
            case ('-'): return first - second;
            case ('*'): return first * second;
            case ('/'): return first / second;
            default: return 0;
        }
    }
    
    // Функция конвертации выражения в массив токенов RPN
    public static List<String> ConvertToRPN(String expression) {
        // Стек для операторов
        Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<>();
        // Результирующий массив токенов
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        // Последнее что рассматривалось был оператор?
        boolean lastIsOperator = true;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
            char c = expression.charAt(i);
            // Если рассматриваемый символ цифра или точка (начало double)
            // То добавляем это число в tokens, и пропускаем number.length() итераций
            if (Character.isDigit(c) || c == '.') {
                String number = GetStringNumber(expression, i);
                tokens.add(number);
                i += number.length() - 1;
                lastIsOperator = false;
            } 
            // Если символ это открывающая скобка, то закидываем её в стек операторов
            else if (c == '(') {
                operatorStack.push(c);
                lastIsOperator = false;
            } 
            // Если же закрывающая, то пока мы не дойдем до открывающей скобки
            // складываем все операторы в tokens. Удаляя так же из стека и '('
            else if (c == ')') {
                while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && operatorStack.peek() != '(') {
                    tokens.add("" + operatorStack.pop());
                }
                operatorStack.pop();
                lastIsOperator = false;
            } 
            // Если рассматриваемый символ это оператор
            else if (operationPriority.containsKey(c)) {
                char op = c;
                // Если мы нашли - и до этого был рассмотрен оператор
                // то это унарный минус. Заменим на символ для унарного минуса
                if (op == '-' && lastIsOperator)
                    op = '~';
                
                // Убираем из стека операторов все операторы у которых приоритет > приоритета op
                // и добавляем в tokens. Так например если мы найдем -, то сначала добавим с конца
                // все * и /. Т.к. у них приоритет выше
                int opPriority = operationPriority.get(op);
                while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && (operationPriority.get(operatorStack.peek()) >= opPriority)) {
                    tokens.add("" + operatorStack.pop());
                }
                // Добавляем в стек сам оператор
                operatorStack.push(op);
                lastIsOperator = true;
            }
        }
        
        // Когда мы прошлись по всей входной строке
        // переносим все из operatorStack в tokens
        while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
            tokens.add("" + operatorStack.pop());
        }
        
        return tokens;
    }
    
    // Функция возвращающая результат выражения
    // Принимает массив токенов RPN
    private static double Calculate(List<String> tokens) {
        // Стек чисел
        Stack<Double> numbers = new Stack<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
            String token = tokens.get(i);
            // Если первый символ токена это число или ., то весь токен это число
            // по этому добавляем его в стек numbers.
            if (Character.isDigit(token.charAt(0)) || token.charAt(0) == '.')
                numbers.push(Double.parseDouble(token));
            // Если token это оператор
            else if (operationPriority.containsKey(token.charAt(0))) {
                // Если токен это оператор унарный минус
                if (token.equals("~")) {
                    // Достаем последнее добавленное в стек число
                    Double last = numbers.pop();
                    // И в стек вставляем результат вычитания из 0 числа last
                    // т.к. -1 = 0 - 1, -x = 0 - x
                    numbers.push(ExecuteOperator('-', 0, last));
                    continue;
                }
                // Достаем числа, где последнее добавленное это второе
                // а предпоследнее это первое
                double second = numbers.pop();
                double first = numbers.pop();
                // Добавляем результат операции
                numbers.push(ExecuteOperator(token.charAt(0), first, second));
            }
        }
        // Последнее оставшееся в стеке число и будет результатом
        return numbers.pop();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String expression = "-(1 + ((2 - -3) * 4) / 5) + 10";
        System.out.println("Expression: " + expression);
        List<String> tokens = ConvertToRPN(expression);
        System.out.println("Tokens: " + tokens.toString());
        double result = Calculate(tokens);
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Тест №1 - длинное выражение взятое из статьи, о которой я написал выше.

```
Expression: 15/(7-(1+1))*3-(2+(1+1))*15/(7-(200+1))*3-(2+(1+1))*(15/(7-(1+1))*3-(2+(1+1))+15/(7-(1+1))*3-(2+(1+1)))
Tokens: [15, 7, 1, 1, +, -, /, 3, *, 2, 1, 1, +, +, 15, *, 7, 200, 1, +, -, /, 3, *, -, 2, 1, 1, +, +, 15, 7, 1, 1, +, -, /, 3, *, 2, 1, 1, +, +, -, 15, 7, 1, 1, +, -, /, 3, *, +, 2, 1, 1, +, +, -, *, -]
Result: -30.072164948453608
```

Тест №2 - простое, маленькое выражение использующее в себе все операторы.

```
Expression: -(1 + ((2 - -3) * 4) / 5) + 10
Tokens: [1, 2, 3, ~, -, 4, *, 5, /, +, ~, 10, +]
Result: 5.0
```